# grep the log from only START to the end in shell

Tags: shell

I want to grep the log from only START to the end in shell

I am using this script but getting only up to TIME as there is a space?

```
cat cdrdump_test.log |
while read line
    do
       sed -n 's/.*CDRQ]:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p;d' >>new_cdrdump_test.log
    done
echo "done"
```

LOG::

> 2017-02-13 08:16:14,808 [20170213081614665-88] INFO       nxl.vxml.manager.VxmlSessionManager (   807) - [TRX-20170213081614665-88][CALLFLOW]  [CDRQ]:START|START|>>ACTION=TM2CM.ALERTING,SYSTEMIDENTIFIER=192.168.100.10,SESSIONID=20170213081614665-88,MSISDN=773930863,CHANNEL=24,DNIS=851851255777759523,TYPE=IBD,CID=-1,TRUNK=2,VXML=null,BOARD=1,DOMAIN=GSM,PROMO=DEFAULT,DIAL_TIME=null,OPTIONS={},TIME=13-02-2017 08:16:14.0666|STARTTIME=1486984574666|<>ACTION=TM2CM.CONNECTED,SYSTEMIDENTIFIER=192.168.100.10,SESSIONID=20170213081614665-88,TIME=13-02-2017 08:16:14.0760|<>ACTION=CM2CM.LOG,SYSTEMIDENTIFIER=192.168.100.10,SESSIONID=20170213081614665-88,MESSAGE=CRBT_STATUS:NoRecord,TIME=13-02-2017 08:16:14.0806|<

Comment: Is the log really all a single long line?  Anyway, the `while` loop is superfluous (and the [`cat` doubly so](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)), just run `sed` on the file directly.  Your current attempt does not have a file name so `sed` will be forever waiting for something to arrive on its standard input.

Comment: If you don't want to stop at the first space, replace `[^ ]*` with `.*`

Comment: The log entry appears to be a single line when looked at in the editor.  Is it really a single line?  If so, you need to explain more clearly what you want.  It might be 'all the material after _some pattern_ on each line'.  Your script running `sed` once per line is dire; you should be able run `sed` once with the file as the argument.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. The title says you want to use `grep`, your code (ab)uses `sed` and you have tagged it `shell`. What are you actually trying to do please?

Answer (score 0):

echo "started "
cat cdrdump_test.log| while read line
  do
    sed -n 's/.*CDRQ]:(.*).*/\1/p;d' >>DeleteEND.log
  done
echo "start1"
cat DeleteEND.log| while read line
    do
        sed s/'\w*$'// >>Final_test.log
    done
echo "end"